# SQL Server help tables?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

If I write in SQL Server :

```
SELECT number FROM master..spt_values WHERE Type = 'P' ORDER BY Number
```

I get a list of sequential numbers which I can **already** use, *instead* of writing a table with sequential numbers.

This can be much helpful for small joins, row numbering etc.

I was wondering if there are other *hidden tables* like this one which can help me do other things as well? For example, I might want to `select someNonImportantTextColmn from master..unknown` and to apply a function of mine.

Where can I find a complete list of these "*help tables*"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`spt_values` is not exactly a help table for your use. It is an undocumented system table used by internal stored procedures for a variety of tasks.

Since it contains neither unique nor contiguous numbers, and because it is undocumented and unsupported (and could simply vanish in a future version), I strongly recommend you *don't* use this table for anything.

You can always generate a sequence based on `row_number` from documented and supported system views, such as `sys.all_objects`, `sys.all_columns`, or a cross join of the two if you need a large number.

Or just [build a `Numbers` table and store the numbers for yourself](http://web.archive.org/web/20150411042510/http://web.archive.org/web/20150411042510/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-numbers-table.html). This is likely to be more efficient in most cases because, if you use it enough, it will always be accessed in memory without having to calculate the sequence.

Comment: Also see this series : http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1 http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2 http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3